# variable value depending on the view

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make an angularjs app, I used the angularJS routing for the different views.
What I'm trying to do is have a variable that changes its value depending on the view I'm in, I tried to make a function :

```
$scope.set_variable = function(param){
        $rootScope.variable = param;
    }
```

then call the function with ng-click in HTML :

```
<div class="collection blue" ng-controller="AccueilCtrl">
            <a href="#/Accueil" ng-click="set_variable(accueil)" class="collection-item blue darken-2 white-text text-darken-2"><i class="material-icons mdi-action-home "></i> Accueil <span class="badge white lighten-2">Vous Ãªtes ici</span></a>
            <a href="#/Effectifs" ng-click="set_variable(effectif)" class="collection-item blue darken-2 white-text text-darken-2"><i class="material-icons mdi-action-supervisor-account "></i> Effectifs</a>
            <a href="#/Absences" ng-click="set_variable(absences)" class="collection-item blue darken-2 white-text text-darken-2"><i class="material-icons mdi-action-today "></i> Absences</a>
            <a href="#/Carto" ng-click="set_variable(carto)" class="collection-item blue darken-2 white-text text-darken-2"><i class="material-icons mdi-action-room "></i> Carto</a>
        </div>
```

but that wasn't a success, could you please help me do it ? or tell me why this isn't working ?

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? That was't a success!!??

Comment: what I'm trying to do is have a variable that changes its value depending on the view that I select

Comment: and?? Isn't it updating?

Comment: No ("that wasn't a success") , actually I don't get anything in console and using the plugin "batarang" I see the message "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: This error has nothing in relation to your code posted!. 
1) Check for circular dependencies.
2) Check for infinite loop in routing

Comment: It only appears when I add this function, any idea how it can be done ? Is this the right way to do it ?

Comment: Because I need to get this variable into an other function afterwards

Comment: @Sudheer you were right, I defined the same function in different scopes that's the cause of the loop I guess, but now I don't have any output ..

Answer (score 0):

In the controller of each view, inject $rootScope and then change the value of the variable using : 
$rootScope.variable = value; 
No need for different functions or ng-click because the controller is excecuted on its own when the view is called